# Using Resource-Level Permissions to restrict user access in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have a Elastic Beanstalk application running on an EC2 instance, currently I have given admin privileges to all my co-workers. However now I want to add other environments and web applications that I don't want my co-workers to have access to. I've been looking at [Resource-Level Permissions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/resource-level-permissions-for-ec2-controlling-management-access-on-specific-instances/) but I'm pulling my hair out trying to get it to work. Sometimes It works intermittently and I'm looking for advice on how I can achieve this from anyone with previous experience.

In a nutshell: I have [Application A] that I want users to have access to. I also have [Application B] and [Application C] that I want to restrict access to so only I can see and make changes to it.

Here is my current IAM Policy JSON;

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ecs:*",
            "ecr:*",
            "elasticloadbalancing:*",
            "autoscaling:*",
            "cloudwatch:*",
            "sns:*",
            "cloudformation:*",
            "dynamodb:*",
            "rds:*",
            "sqs:*",
            "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
            "iam:ListRolePolicies",
            "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
            "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
            "iam:ListRoles",
            "iam:ListServerCertificates",
            "acm:DescribeCertificate",
            "acm:ListCertificates",
            "codebuild:CreateProject",
            "codebuild:DeleteProject",
            "codebuild:BatchGetBuilds",
            "codebuild:StartBuild"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:myregion:myaccountid:instance/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/Name":"mytag"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticbeanstalk:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:myregion:myaccountid:environment/myapp/myenv"
        ],
        "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Derived from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.managed-policies.html). I would really appreciate if someone with more experience with IAM policies could identify what I'm doing wrong and how to do it properly & If there is a simpler way of doing this I would love to hear it also!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since your co-workers already have admin access, you need a Deny policy.
The following policy explicitly denies access to all Amazon EB resources other than the listed resources

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": "elasticbeanstalk:*",
    "NotResource": [
      "<Application A ARN>"
    ]
  }
}
```